# Backing up and restoring only certain tables in an Advantage Database

Tags: advantage-database-server

When making a backup in Advantage, we want to only backup some tables that hold some structural data.  These tables may change in a database update, but most of the tables will not.  The other tables contain enormous amounts of blob data: potentially 10s of gigs.

If something does go awry in the database update, and we want to restore the backed up tables, what are our options to keep the original large tables, but restore the selected tables? Restore them to the existing database, keeping the old large tables in place? Free the large tables and add them to the newly restored database?

(Note: no RI rules between the backup up tables and the large tables, but the large tables do reference autoincs in the backed-up tables.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inclusion lists to limit the tables that are backed up or restored.  For example, if you are using the adsbackup.exe command line utility, you could restrict the backup to two tables:

```
adsbackup -i"table1,table2" test.add c:\mypath\backup\
```

Then with a restore, you can also restrict it to specific files:

```
adsbackup -r -i"table1,table2" c:\mypath\backup\test.add c:\mypath\restore\test.add
```

Note that when specifying a restore operation with an inclusion list, the dictionary (.add) file will only be restored if it does not already exist.  So if you restore to an existing dictionary with an inclusion list, it will only copy the specified tables.

Comment: So restoring to an existing dictionary with an inclusion list would keep the data from the non-included tables?  This won't cause table out of sync with dictionary issues for the non-included tables?

Comment: @EricG: In general, no it won't because the dictionary is not copied (if you restore to an existing location). But if there is any kind of correlation between the non-restored tables and the restored ones, then it would lead to logical inconsistencies (you say there is no RI, but sometimes databases end up with implied correlations over time).

Comment: Awesome.  I'll double check and run some test to make sure we haven't missed anything.  Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: @EricG:  One thing to watch is if one of the backed up and restored tables has had a structural change when restoring to an existing database.  It won't be able to restore if the structure has changed (since it does not update the dictionary when using the inclusion list). In that situation you would need to either manually change the table structure back to match the backup.  Or restore to a new location and then use SQL statements to restore the data to the table with the new structure.